# Drupal 7 - Creating a recipe website

Tags: drupal, recipe, custom-pages

I'm new to drupal and just curious about that what are the steps to create a recipe website, where Admin user and specific members could enter the recipes, and web site would be able to show each recipe on separate page as well as in listings.

There is a popular module named "Recipe" to download and install but I don't want to use that module to have a full control on my website.

I installed the module Field Collection (for a list of ingredients) and created a custom node where an admin user can enter all the required data for a recipe. I also created a taxonomy of categories and attached with the node where user can select a recipe category. No issue.  Now my questions are:

1. How can I add whole recipe categorized list in a tree shape on my web site?
2. How can I make this list to be populate automatically as the user create a new node?
3. I want to make a custom page where each recipe would be shown individually. How can I do this. (I read something about Panels and Views and tried them a little. But I can find "field collections" only while preparing the views and not the all fields I created in my custom node)

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'm sorry I might couldn't explain myself. I want to make a website similar to http://www.simplyrecipes.com with sub-catagorizing, and where members could add their own recipes as well. But I want to have a complete design control over the listing and individual recipe page. I hope I made myself clear now. If anyone need more explaination I'm open. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't quite understand you I'm afraid.
2. Sounds like you want to create a [view](http://drupal.org/project/views) for displaying your nodes.
3. Surely this is just the node page itself?

Comment: 1. do you mean how to list them like in a menu with hierakies? 'taxmonomy menu' would be the right module, if the "tree" should be like the category.  
3. To be in complete control you should make a custom template file for that specific content type.

Comment: for point number 1, yes, this is what I wanted to ask. Thanks